# Aspectj maven plugin & jetty-all compile warning

Tags: java, maven, jetty, aspectj

I use aspectj-maven-plugin and jetty-all in my java project.

But after run "mvn clean install" there will be a warning message.

```
....
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile (default) @ as ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[WARNING] incorrect classpath: /home/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/9.3.8.v20160314/jetty-all-9.3.8.v20160314.pom
        <unknown source file>:<no line information>
....
```

If I remove aspectj maven plugin there will be no warning.

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xxx</name>
    <url>xxx</url>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
      ...
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <finalName>xxx</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>xxx.xxx.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>xxx.xxx.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="svn"
                                      failifexecutionfails="false"
                                      output="${project.build.directory}/classes/svn.txt">
                                    <arg line="info"/>
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <extdirs>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</extdirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. -->
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>xxx</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>xxx</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Could anybody tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Could you please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) on GitHub? There are many things involved, I would like to see the full picture and not try to parse your POM in my head, looking for possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

The warning that you get to see are generated by the plugin used :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
        <bootclasspath><!--try including correct classpath here--></bootclasspath> 
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <proc>none</proc>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <goals>
               <goal>compile</goal>
               <goal>test-compile</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```